# How can I store variable changed by user?

Tags: python, application-development, quickly

I'm working on simple application for Ubuntu App Showdown. I'm relatively new to programming (started learning Python last week), so maybe this question sounds stupid.

Anyway, lets say there's a variable which the user can change. Lets say its users name. How can I store it, so after next run of the program, this name will be displayed? Can I write changes to the file with the variable or do I need to create special file where I can write changes?

I use Quickly for the record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save it in database or in a simple textfile(if it is small project) . I hope you already learned filemanagement in python

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think the text file will be enough. I don't know where that file should be stored. Should it be in hidden folder (for example `.my-app`) in user directory or somewhere in /opt together with other files from my application?

Comment: It is better to store user data and user configurations in .appname folder in home directory . You should save global settings in /opt